# Can I make free shipping on a specified product in magento 1?

Tags: magento-1, free-shipping

I need to create a new product which my customer need not to pay shipping amount for this (ex: free shipping), but, it doesn't work, here is the snapshot for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> If you want per product basis shipment then you can go with below
>   approach

There are ready extension available in market you can use directly.

**Free** :
https://github.com/micronax/magento-attributeshipping

**Paid** : 
https://marketplace.magento.com/kaushik-distance-based-shipping-charge.html

If you want to make your own then create basic shipping extension and with in that you can write down your `collectRates` as per your logic, you can take reference of below code for that

```
class Fgits_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Customrate extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
    protected $_code = 'fgits_customrate';
    protected $_isFixed = true;
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!$destCountry = strtolower($request->getDestCountryId())) {
        return false;
    }
    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    // Some meta-information
    $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
    $method->setCarrier('fgits_customrate');
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
    $method->setMethod('fgits_customrate');
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
    // Check if cart total exceeds setting value
    $maxCartValue = floatval($this->getConfigData('maxCartValue'));
    if ($maxCartValue > 0 && $this->getCartTotal() >= $maxCartValue) {
        return false;
    }
    // Calculate shipping cost
    if (!$orderShippingCost = $this->determineShippgingCost($destCountry)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Set shipping cost
    $method->setPrice($orderShippingCost);
    $method->setCost($orderShippingCost);
    $result->append($method);
    return $result;
    }
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
    return array('fgits_customrate' => $this->getConfigData('name'));
    }
    public function determineShippgingCost($countryCode)
    {
    $cart = $this->getCart();
    $cart_items = $cart->getAllItems();
    $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
    $fn_name = 'getShippingCost'.ucfirst($countryCode);
    $cartShippingCost = 0.0;
    foreach($cart_items as $items) {
        $cur_fproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($items->getProduct_id());
        if ($shippingCost = $_helper->productAttribute($cur_fproduct, $cur_fproduct->$fn_name(), 'shipping_cost'.$countryCode)) {
            if ($cartShippingCost < $shippingCost) {
                $cartShippingCost = $shippingCost;
            }
        } else return false;
    }
    return (float) $cartShippingCost;
    }
    private function getCartTotal() {
    $quote = $this->getCart();
    $items = $quote->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $priceInclVat += $item->getRowTotalInclTax();
    }
    return $priceInclVat;
    return Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($priceInclVat);
    }
    private function getCart() {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    return $session->getQuote();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, let me see, and also why my magento showing rupee symbol in admin panel when i got an order from international store (dollar)?

Comment: @YKB because may be your default currency is rupee , so in admin it always show your default currency

Comment: Great! How will I come to know what currency is default on my Magento?

Comment: @YKB follow this blog https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-default-language-and-currency.html

Comment: @YKB If my answer solves your concern then mark as accepted so future take benefit from this post

Comment: Finally, got it and done!